# SQLite query running on DBeaver but Syntax error in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to run the exact same query on the exact same database on two different setups. One of them returns a syntax error, the other processes the query without any problem. I am trying to understand the reason.

Setups:

1. In python on Ubuntu server with python sqlite3 (v3.22.0) <- SYNTAX ERROR HERE
2. In DBeaver with sqlite (v3.36.0) <- ALL FINE HERE

The query is:

```
SELECT sub2.mbid AS newmbid, sub1.mbid AS oldmbid, sub2.released FROM (
             select mbid, name_full, artist, released, artist_lower, name,
                       row_number() OVER (partition by artist_lower, name order by name) as rn
                from (
                    select mbid, name_full, artist, released, artist_lower, name,
                    replace(case when substr(name, 1, (instr(name, '-'))-1) ='' then name else substr(name, 1, (instr(name, '-'))-1) end,' ','') as name
                    from (
                        select mbid, name as name_full, artist, released,
                               lower(artist) as artist_lower,
                               replace(lower(case when substr(name, 1, (instr(name, '('))-1) ='' then name else substr(name, 1, (instr(name, '('))-1) end),' ','') as name
                        from songs
                    ) as sub
                ) as sub
                ) sub1
            INNER JOIN (
            select mbid, name_full, artist, released, artist_lower, name, min(released) FROM (
                select mbid, name_full, artist, released, artist_lower, name,
                   row_number() OVER (partition by artist_lower, name order by name) as rn
            from (
                select mbid, name_full, artist, released, artist_lower, name,
                replace(case when substr(name, 1, (instr(name, '-'))-1) ='' then name else substr(name, 1, (instr(name, '-'))-1) end,' ','') as name
                from (
                    select mbid, name as name_full, artist, released,
                           lower(artist) as artist_lower,
                           replace(lower(case when substr(name, 1, (instr(name, '('))-1) ='' then name else substr(name, 1, (instr(name, '('))-1) end),' ','') as name
                    from songs
                ) as sub
            ) as sub
            ) as sub GROUP BY artist_lower, name
            ) sub2
            on sub1.artist_lower = sub2.artist_lower
            and sub1.name = sub2.name
```

The way I run the query on python is:

```
import sqlite3
self.connection = sqlite3.connect("my.db") 
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
q = """The query from above goes here"""
self.cursor.execute(q)
```

What could possibly be the reason? I don't expect any breaking changes in the subversions of sqlite3. Could it be the quotes? But everything is enclosed in a multi-line triple quote string in python, that should be save. Any ideas?

EDIT:
sorry, I should include the error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Window functions were introduced in version 3.25.0 of SQLite. Check your version.

Comment: good point, the version on the server is 3.22.0 as stated above

Comment: Why do you use `row_number()` in the query? It is not used in the joins and it is not selected finally?

Comment: I used it in an earlier version and forgot to remove it. After removing it the query now actually runs. Thanks a lot!